# Need to get a div to show itself two seconds after the page loads

Tags: jquery, css

I need the .affor div to transition in 2 seconds after the page loads; I'm trying to do this with jquery, any advice?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.affor').hide(function(){
    $(this).delay(function(){
      $(this).show();
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.affor{
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  background-color: rgb(39, 60, 79);
  /*border-radius: 100px;*/
  color:white;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;

  transition: 2s ease-in;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class=".affor"> Hello </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to read the manual for `.delay()`. Also, you should not have `.` inside classes. In CSS, you use `.` for classes. You need to use something like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.affor').hide(0, function() {
    $(this).delay(2000).fadeIn(1000);
  });
});
```

```css
.affor {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: rgb(39, 60, 79);
  /*border-radius: 100px;*/
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  transition: 2s ease-in;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="affor">Hello</div>
```

Since your `display` is set to `flex`, the right way of fading in won't work.

Answer (score 2):

You *can* achieve this effect with jQuery.

But (perhaps even simpler) you can also achieve it with CSS `@keyframes` alone:

```css
.affor {
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  background-color: rgb(39, 60, 79);
  border-radius: 100px;
  color:white;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  animation: sayHello 3s ease-out;
}

@keyframes sayHello {
  0% {opacity: 0;}
 33% {opacity: 0;}
100% {opacity: 1;}
}
```

```html
<div class="affor">Hello</div>
```